# Help With Persistence and Syslinux File

Tags: 12.04, lubuntu

I'm currently trying to add Persistence to my Lubuntu 12.04 operating system which i am running on 'Try before you install' on a USB drive. My computer has no hard drive so this is the only option.

The instructions for adding Persistence (http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/diskimg/readme.txt) tell me to edit the Syslinux.cfg file, but i cannot see it here, meaning i can't do what i want to do.

Where do i find it guys?

Thanks, UbuntuRob.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the files to edit is now the ...syslinux/txt.cfg
Add the "persistent" on the Try line:
...
menu label ^Try Ubuntu without installing
kernel /casper/vmlinuz
append noprompt cdrom-detect/try-usb=true persistent file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper initrd=/casper/initrd.lz quiet splash --

Also, assumes you have the casper-rw file or a partition labeled "casper-rw" properly formatted to use for writing things.